# How do i use alert builder dialog to display a message

Tags: java, android

I want to use an a dialog to display a message contained in the method below instead of just setText, but each time I use the alertBuilder, the message does not display. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

below is the code:

```
             @Override

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) {

        if (data == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        Camera.Size size = cam.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        if (size == null) throw new NullPointerException();

        if (!processing.compareAndSet(false, true)) return;

        int width = size.width;
        int height = size.height;

        int imgAvg = ImageProcessing.decodeYUV420SPtoRedAvg(data.clone(), height, width);
         Log.i(TAG, "imgAvg="+imgAvg);
        if (imgAvg == 0 || imgAvg == 255) {
            processing.set(false);
            return;
        }

        int averageArrayAvg = 0;
        int averageArrayCnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < averageArray.length; i++) {
            if (averageArray[i] > 0) {
                averageArrayAvg += averageArray[i];
                averageArrayCnt++;
            }
        }

        int rollingAverage = (averageArrayCnt > 0) ? (averageArrayAvg / averageArrayCnt) : 0;
        TYPE newType = currentType;
        if (imgAvg < rollingAverage) {
            newType = TYPE.RED;
            if (newType != currentType) {
                beats++;
                // Log.d(TAG, "BEAT!! beats="+beats);
            }
        } else if (imgAvg > rollingAverage) {
            newType = TYPE.GREEN;
        }

        if (averageIndex == averageArraySize) averageIndex = 0;
        averageArray[averageIndex] = imgAvg;
        averageIndex++;

        // Transitioned from one state to another to the same
        if (newType != currentType) {
            currentType = newType;
            image.postInvalidate();
        }
           long endTime = 20;
                //System.currentTimeMillis();
        double totalTimeInSecs = (endTime - startTime) / 1000d;
        if (totalTimeInSecs >= 20) {
            double bps = (beats / totalTimeInSecs);
            int dpm = (int) (bps * 60d);
            if (dpm < 30 || dpm > 180) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                beats = 0;
                processing.set(false);
                return;
            }

             Log.d(TAG,
             "totalTimeInSecs="+totalTimeInSecs+" beats="+beats);


            if (beatsIndex == beatsArraySize) beatsIndex = 0;
            beatsArray[beatsIndex] = dpm;
            beatsIndex++;

            int beatsArrayAvg = 0;
            int beatsArrayCnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < beatsArray.length; i++) {
                if (beatsArray[i] > 0) {
                    beatsArrayAvg += beatsArray[i];
                    beatsArrayCnt++;
                }
            }
            int beatsAvg = (beatsArrayAvg / beatsArrayCnt);
            //maybe here
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            beats = 0;

            text.setText(String.valueOf(beatsAvg) + "bpm");
        }
```

The code works fine, but I just want to use a dialog to display the text.setText message. How do I do this?

Comment: Please google it you will find out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class DialogCaller {

    public static void showDialog(Context context,String title,String message,
                                  DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setTitle(title);
        dialog.setMessage(message);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",onClickListener);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Add this class to your android project.

whenever you want to display an message just call the class with with context,title,message, and a listener for okay button in dialog. Like this.

**Add the below code in the place of  text.setText(String.valueOf(beatsAvg) + "bpm");**

```
DialogCaller.showDialog(getActivity()/getApplicationContext(),"Kingmeka dialog ",String.valueOf(beatsAvg) + "bpm",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(String.valueOf(beatsAvg) + "bpm");

      alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // Do what needs to be done
         }
      });

      alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
         }
      });

      AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
      alertDialog.show();
```

Use above code for showing your message in alert dialog. Customize it according to your need. For details see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)